# Rails fixture relationship does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.1 app. I'm able to work around it, but interested in why it's not working:

```
class NotificationSettings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :notification_settings
end
```

This does NOT work:

```
# test/fixtures/notification_settings.yml

wilmas_notification_settings:
  user: wilma
  checkin_comments: false
  checkin_comments_schedule: instant
```

This DOES work:

```
# test/fixtures/notification_settings.yml

wilmas_notification_settings:
  user_id: wilma
  checkin_comments: false
  checkin_comments_schedule: instant
```

All things point to it being a problem with the `belongs_to`, but I'm baffled.

Error is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user" of relation "notification_settings" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "notification_settings" ("user", "checkin_commen...
                                             ^
: INSERT INTO "notification_settings" ("user", "checkin_comments", "checkin_comments_schedule") VALUES (550831404, 'f', 'instant')
```

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the pluralization of `notification_settings` was throwing it off. This fixed it:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w(notification_settings)
end
```

Comment: Are you able to expand on this answer in regards to is this a bug in Rails 4? If yes, would I still need to make the changes even if I am not currently using the inflection rules? In the default code it says "These inflection rules are supported but not enabled by default" Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. I think it was just related to the fact that the plural in this case was the same word as the singular, due to the has_one.